# Optimize DPI aware application for custom DPI settings

Tags: c#, windows, graphics, scaling, dpi

I'm writing a DPI aware application. It is currently compatible with 100%, 125%, 150% and 200% scaling. However if I use a custom setting of 130% for example, it takes the code of 200% instead of 125%. Is it possible to optimize my application with all custom DPI settings without having 100 ifs?

I'm currently using the following code:

```
Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
if (g.DpiX < 120)
{
    t.ItemSize = new Size(245, 22);
}
else if (g.DpiX == 120)
{
    t.ItemSize = new Size(329, 28);
}
else if (g.DpiX == 144)
{
    if (g.DpiX > 195)
    {
        t.ItemSize = new Size(494, 44);
    }
    else
    {
        t.ItemSize = new Size(368, 33);
    }
}
else
{
    t.ItemSize = new Size(494, 44);
}
```

EDIT:

Using this code now:

```
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        if (g.DpiX < 120)
        {
            t.ItemSize = new Size(245, 22);
        }
        else if (g.DpiX >= 120 && g.DpiX < 144)
        {
            t.ItemSize = new Size(329, 28);
        }
        else if (g.DpiX >= 144 && g.DpiX < 196)
        {
            if (g.DpiX >= 196)
            {
                t.ItemSize = new Size(494, 44);
            }
            else
            {
                t.ItemSize = new Size(368, 33);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            t.ItemSize = new Size(494, 44);
        }
```

The result is that 200% uses the code of 150% for some reason? Did I miss something?

Comment: Just use else if (g.DpiX >= 120 && g.DpiX < 144) etc.  Actually running into a non-standard dpi setting is going to be *extremely* rare.

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason 200% isn't accepted anymore. See edit.

Comment: That doesn't win any prizes, but try not to get hung up on a couple of if() statements.  Use a debugger.

Comment: It seems to work now.